# The following Node module returns "undefined", but why?

Tags: javascript, return, return-value, node-modules

Below is a module that takes one argument, a number, and then either adds or subtracts a const, magicNumber, from it depending on whether or not the number is even or odd, respectively. When I run this code, however, I simply get "undefined." What am I doing wrong?

```
module.exports = (number) => {

    let answer;  //Answer is declared in the global scope
    const magicNumber = 5;  //magicNumber is declared in the global scope

    if (number % 2) {  //If the number is even
        add(number);  //run the number through the add function
    } else {  //otherwise run the number through the subtract function
        subtract(number);
    }

    function add(number){  //Function takes the number as argument, does the math, and returns the value of answer.
        answer = number + magicNumber;
        return answer;
    }

    function subtract(number){  //Function takes the number as argument, does the math, and returns the value of answer.
        answer = number - magicNumber;
        return answer;
    }
};
```

Comment: Your function isn't returning anything, so the return value is `undefined` by default (also, comments need to be delimited with `/*` / `*/` or, on a single line, with `//` (`*` alone won't work)

Comment: You need to return something from your function, like `return add(number);` and `return subtract(number)`

Comment: It is difficult to understand if the code not shown as code is intentional or not (e.g. the first line "module.exports..." and the final line "};" are not displaying as code in your question. Your question should also include the code you're using to call the module.

Answer (score 2):

Your exported block is not returning anything hence it’s undefined by default.

```
module.exports = (number) => {
let answer;  //Answer is declared in the global scope
const magicNumber = 5;  //magicNumber is declared in the global scope

if (number % 2) {  //If the number is even
    return add(number);  //you should return here as well
} else {  //otherwise run the number through the subtract function
    return subtract(number);//you should return here as well 
}

function add(number){  //Function takes the number as argument, does the math, and returns the value of answer.
    answer = number + magicNumber;
    return answer;
}

function subtract(number){  //Function takes the number as argument, does the math, and returns the value of answer.
    answer = number - magicNumber;
    return answer;
}
};
```

Comment: My logic was that since one or the other function, add() or subtract(), respectively, would inevitably be called and each of those have their own returns, the intended outcome of the code would inevitably be returned. It's confusing to me that return statements would have to drive the continual execution of the code at every step when it seems intuitive that once either of the lines add(number); or subtract(number); are hit, those functions would run and would return values regardless. I'm currently researching this but finding nothing. Is there something fundamental I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: In JavaScript and almost all programming languages return statement is block based